# react native scrollview not smooth when app opend from background

Tags: react-native

i created simple app in react native ,everything works fine 
but when the app go to background then active again
Scrollview not working smoothly
can some one have solution?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the direct solution, but did you consider using `<FlatList>` instead of `<ScrollView>` given the former is more performant when it comes to rendering long lists.

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution

i Uninstalled `react-native-fbsdk` and everything works fine